# What is the difference between 2 array unset

Tags: tcl

We have 2 ways to unset an element in an array: `unset` and `array unset`. What is the difference?

Here is my code:

```
>cat /tmp/arr_unset.tcl
proc parr {arr} {
    global arr1
    foreach {str num} [array get $arr] {
        puts "$str:$num"
    }
}

array set arr1 {one 1 two 2 three 3}
parr arr1

array unset arr1 two
parr arr1

unset arr1(one)
parr arr1
```

Here is the run:

```
>tclsh /tmp/arr_unset.tcl
three:3
two:2
one:1
three:3
one:1
three:3
```

Seems they are same, or the above code does not expose the difference?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation for `array unset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm#M15):

> **array unset** *arrayName ?pattern?*
>
> Unsets all of the elements in the array that match pattern (using the matching rules of string match). If arrayName is not the name of an array variable or there are no matching elements in the array, no error will be raised. If pattern is omitted and arrayName is an array variable, then the command unsets the entire array. The command always returns an empty string.

It deletes all entries matching a wildcard pattern (Or all entries if not given a pattern); `unset` deletes a specific entry.

Example:

```
% array set foo {cat 1 dog 2 cow 3}
% parray foo
foo(cat) = 1
foo(cow) = 3
foo(dog) = 2
% array unset foo c*
% parray foo
foo(dog) = 2
```

Comment: NB: `unset` can also delete the whole array; on an array, `unset ary` and `array unset ary` are equivalent. (I wonder at the use case that led to `array unset`, but that was before my time...)

Comment: Tcl arrays are hashes. Multidimensional arrays can be simulated by joining the keys with some separator. An example of a use case would be array elements such as: `userdata(user1,name)`. Then to delete all information related to user1, you can use `array unset userdata user1,*`.